# Can't get ec2_client.describe_instances() to print instances passed as parameter

Tags: python, amazon-ec2, aws-sdk, boto3

I'm having a hard time trying to figure out how to make the code below to take InstanceID as parameter and display info only about this instance:

```
import boto3

ec2_client = boto3.client('ec2')

instance_data = []
instanceid = 'i-123456'
def get_instace_data(instanceid):
    reservations = ec2_client.describe_instances()
    for reservation in reservations['Reservations']:
        for instance in reservation['Instances']:
            instance_data.append(
                        {
                            'instanceId': instance['InstanceId'],
                            'instanceType': instance['InstanceType'],
                            'launchDate': instance['LaunchTime'].strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f')
                        }
                    )
    print(instance_data)



get_instace_data(instanceid)
```

My understanding is that get_instance_data() should be taking the instance ID and display only info for that instance, even though it iterates to the whole 'Reservations' dict that returned.

Am i missing something here?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you see the argument `instanceid` used anywhere in the function?

Comment: That is true, however, i'm failing to understand how can i incorporate the instanceid inside the function, could you shed some light? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Your code will append **all** instances to the `instance_data`.
In order to receive only required instance you need change

```
reservations = ec2_client.describe_instances()
```

To the following:

```
reservations = ec2_client.describe_instances(
    Filters=
    InstanceIds=['i-123456'])
```

Answer (score 1):

[describe_instance()](http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/ec2.html#EC2.Client.describe_instances) let you specify filters, however, the syntax can be quite confusing. Because you can specify instance ID inside the Filters parameter or inside InsanceIds parameter.

e.g.

```
# method 1 
response = client.describe_instances(
    InstanceIds=[
        'i-123456',
    ],
)

# method 2 
response = client.describe_instances(
    Filters=[
        {
            'Name': 'instance-id',
            'Values': ['i-123456']
        },
    ],
)
```

The documentation showing *Filters (list)* is utterly confusing, because the only way to pass in the correct filtering name into the list, you must embrace the "Name" and "Value" explicitly inside a dict.

```
# This will not works
response = client.describe_instances(
    Filters=[
          'instance-id:i-123456'
        ])
# Neither will this! 
response = client.describe_instances(
    Filters=[
          {'instance-id': ['i-123456']}
        ])
```